# Add new Object data Using PHP Laravel (Array_push)

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Array one:

```
[
    'jabatan' => 'required',
    'tipe_kegiatan' => 'required',
    'waktu' => 'required',
    'nrt' => 'required',
    0 => [
        'materi' => 'required',
        'metode' => 'required',
        'hasil' => 'required',
        'img' => 'required|image|max:1024',
    ]
];
```

Array two:

```
[
    'jabatan' => 'required',
    'tipe_kegiatan' => 'required',
    'waktu' => 'required',
    'nrt' => 'required',
    'materi' => 'required',
    'metode' => 'required',
    'hasil' => 'required',
    'img' => 'required|image|max:1024',
];
```

### how to change the data array as shown below

Change Data `array one` to `array two` (I try using `array_push` but I don't get the wanted result)

My case:
I have 2 conditions where if the user inputs by selecting form type 1 then the validation will adjust to form 1 and if the user selects input with form 2 then the validation also adjusts to form 2. all processes are in one post request action.

Comment: please fix your links

Comment: so you want to know how to turn array 1 into array 2?

Answer (score 0):

you should use array_merge like this:

```
<?php
$a1=["red","green"];
$a2=["blue","yellow"];
print_r(array_merge($a1,$a2));
?>
```